# Angularjs Image Compress passing value into $scope model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to ask, so I came across this angular [image compress function](https://github.com/sammychl/ng-image-compress) which works great as per what I want. I have successfully implement it to work but there is 1 problem, the compress function returns me with a base64 encoded image which is stored in a local `$scope` and can only be called in the `html` page itself if I am not mistaken like such.

```
<td style="width: 15%">
    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <img class="canvas-image" ng-src="<%image1.compressed.dataURL%>"/></div>
</td>
<td>
     <input id="inputImage" ngf-select ng-model="statusData.file" ngf-multiple=false type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.5" resize-type="png" />
 </td>
```

In order for me to get the compressed image I have to echo the base64 code by calling `<%image1.compressed.dataURL%>`

Now my problem is how should I pass this value into the $scope model that i have created specifically to store this value? I tried doing something like

`<%$scope.imageCache.data = image1.compressed.dataURL%>` but it did not work.

I need the conpressed data to be passed into my custom module so I can perform other actions with the image.

Here is a [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3LgLIq7y1fEHllX8wBfo?p=preview) of the code working code

Hopefully someone can help me in such scenario.

**Update 1:** Found a temporary cheating workaround is by calling `ng-click="image1 = null"` when user click on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-src` is a directive that evaluates its content. Thus you should provide a value from your `$scope`.

```
<img class="canvas-image" ng-src="image1.compressed.dataURL"/>
```

This will provide the data given that in `$scope.image1.compressed.dataURL` you have correct data.

So without using `ng-src` it would be

```
<img class="canvas-image" src="{{image1.compressed.dataURL}}"/>
```

Or with your modified interpolation symbols

```
<img class="canvas-image" src="<%image1.compressed.dataURL%>"/>
```